# Not all images load on site once uploaded to server

Tags: html, image

I have been building a gallery site and in the interest of time I purchased a template. All of the code worked off-line and on my computer. Now that I have uploaded the website some images show up and some do not.

Here's what I do know:
All images are on the server, I verified this.

I must be missing something in the  tags because they all appear to be uniform to me, but in spite of this two images in particular show up while the remaining 25 of so do not.

The website in question is http://www.ddcr2.net

Here's a section of code from one of the two images that actually display:

```
<div class="gallery_item">
<div class="gallery_item_padding">
<div class="gallery_item_wrapper"><a href="http://ddcr2.net/img/gallery/600_600/equipmentzoom4.jpg" class="prettyPhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title=""></a>
<img class="gallery-stand-img" src="http://ddcr2.net/img/gallery/570_570/equipment4.jpg" alt="" width="570" height="570">
<div class="gallery_fadder"></div>
<span class="gallery_ico"></span>
</div></div></div>
```

And here's a section of code from one that does not display:

```
<div class="gallery_item">
<div class="gallery_item_padding">
<div class="gallery_item_wrapper"><a href="http://ddcr2.net/img/gallery/600_600/equipmentzoom1.jpg" class="prettyPhoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title=""></a>
<img class="gallery-stand-img" src="http://ddcr2.net/img/gallery/570_570/equipment1.jpg" alt="" width="570" height="570">
<div class="gallery_fadder"></div>
<span class="gallery_ico"></span>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: code blurbs didn't appear for some odd reason.. any ideas as to why? haha

Comment: from what I saw the only problem (if all images are really in the server) is the filename/path off/to the image. Check it again.

here is an example of an image broken: `http://www.ddcr2.net/img/gallery/570_570/coverequip.jpg`

Comment: "All images are on the server, I verified this." -> how did you verify?

Comment: I just logged into the FTP and made sure everything uploaded properly. Not so sure what's wrong with the image path - is it not supposed to be linked as http? It didn't work with the original code which was just img/gallery/...etc

Comment: @debernardi I think you can agree that calling them via the URL in the browser is not working - maybe try uploading a dummy .txt file to the same folder and see if you can load it

Comment: this image .. http://ddcr2.net/img/gallery/570_570/equipment1.jpg .. doesn't appear to exist on the server in that location

Comment: Check your console in [bathroom gallery](http://www.ddcr2.net/bathrooms.html). You have 75 errors. Either images aren't on the server or your using wrong paths.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I feel utterly stupid for this. The file names were capitalized and I did not account for case sensitivity on a browser. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your server isn't giving back the images, just try this direct-link (extracted from a img-tag): [click](http://www.ddcr2.net/img/gallery/570_570/coverequip.jpg). In your position I would do the following things:

- Are the files really on the server? The path looks like a plain folder-structure, so you should be able to clarify this very easily.
- Is there a pattern in the file size? Are the denied files larger than the other?
- Are all files .jpg? Not .jpeg, .png, etc?
- Are permissions on file-level populated correctly?

**Edit**

Questioner was able to fix it, so the link now points to a valid image.